# OpenGL: Why are things bound instead of being passed directly as parameters?

Tags: api-design, opengl

In OpenGL you have to bind an object to the context to be used in subsequent calls, instead of just using it as an argument in those calls.

For example, in OpenGL you write this

```
glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts.size(), verts.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

Instead of something like this:

```
glGenBuffers( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1, &vbo );
glBufferData( vbo, verts.size(), verts.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

I wonder, what was the reason behind that decision? Was there a technical reason for this?

Comment: Surely this is a question to ask of the OpenGL developers?

Comment: Just a small note - the API you suggested would be more logical and consistent with the buffer type passed to `glBufferData`: `glGenBuffers(1, &vbo); glBufferData(vbo, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts.size(), verts.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

Comment: @Sergey `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` shouldn't even be there, it's a name for a bind point not a type.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39921879/734069)

Answer (score 7):

Because legacy. Just about every feature in modern opengl started out as an (optional) extension which had to work nicely when it's there but not used. This means that a lot of the features are based around persistent state.

The oldest opengl versions which had glDrawArrays didn't even have buffers, instead the `void*` pointer in `glVertexAttribPointer` (back then they were actually `glVertexPointer`/`glNormalPointer`/...) always referred to user space memory instead of an offset into the buffer bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. To make the buffers work with that they had to create the bind points to add the bound buffer as a hidden parameter to existing methods. From there it's logical to use that bind point for the new methods as well to maintain uniformity.

A lot of opengl is bind-to-edit, which Khronos acknowledges is a bad api design. This is why the DSA extensions came about and is now part of the core API since 4.5. These lets you do `glNamedBufferData( vbo, verts.size() * sizeof(verts[0]), verts.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );` to create and upload your mesh.

Comment: Legacy and the fact that OpenGL is a gigantic state machine.

Comment: @whatsisname: "*the fact that OpenGL is a gigantic state machine*" I don't really know what you mean by that, but that fact hasn't stopped DSA from existing.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I refer to how OpenGl draws depends a great deal on its global state, and the developer must pay close attention to maintaining order to those changes in state, as opposed to typical programming where global state is avoided as much as possible and carefully compartmentalized.

Comment: @whatsisname the actual question is why did opengl become a gigantic state machine.

Comment: @ratchetfreak that has already been discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194002/why-does-opengl-be-designed-as-a-state-machine-originally